# Effect of storing data using SharedPreferences in onpause android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, application-state

I am storing my data structure values in  `SharedPreferences`  in `onPause()` methode of activity The SP.xml file size becomes  25K , will there be any effect of doing this storing in `onPause()` method if yes then What should I do to Store may datastructure in `SharedPreferences` .

Comment: Why don't you store it on Application Directory ??. It is private and only accessible by your app only

Comment: @BrijeshThakur And you can also make `SharedPreferences` as private. Don't you?

Comment: Yes but It's not recommended to store large data using Shared Preferences. You can read page for more information : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: @BrijeshThakur Is 25K is large Data for Shared Preferences Is there any general file size limit  or no. of data types stored limit for  Shared Preferences

Comment: 25K is still Ok. But I would recommend for Private App Directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

25k is not extremely large but I still wouldn't recommend it. Depending on the needs and complexity of your app, you could look into an [SQLite database](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) or [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) your data and put it in an [internal file](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

Comment: I have total 100s of variable in 5 classes sowhile serializing class do I need to serialize each of its variable ?

Comment: Yes. Anything you need to save should be serialized. Most built-in java classes have serialization built into them. If you have created custom stuff, you need to write serialization routines for them.

Comment: My Shared Preferences requires 40mS to store my data will it affect any way on my app I am doing it in onPause method ?

Comment: 40ms is not too long. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

Storing in `SharedPreferences` lets you access your data virtually everywhere in the same application. Unless you need that data like a token or anything else small but significant you shouldn't do that (bad practice since it makes your application heavy)
. It would be better to pass the information in a bundle if you are switching activities or fragment or save it in `OnPause()` to have the data when the application is resumed or `OnSaveInstance()` for rotation.

Answer (score 0):

But unless its too much of structured Data, I would prefer SQLite. Throwing 100 select queries feels odd !!